# Add clear icon on kendo UI search textbox

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I´m using kendo UI Jquery for my web, and I used some components like the Kendo Multiselect it has clear icon on the right and its provided by the control by default.

```
<div>
  <label for="simple-input">Input</label>
  <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

My question is does this functionality exists for a normal text box? or should I implement it :V

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with kendo css, you will get an `x` icon at the far right of the input box when the box has focus.

https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/otUrArax

[image]

```
<p>
  <label for="simple-input">Input</label>
  <input id="simple-input" type="text" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="simple-search">Search</label>
  <input id="simple-search" type="search" class="k-textbox" style="width: 100%;" />
</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I followed the link from firefox and the x is not displayed, it is only working for chrome for the search textbox, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, it seems that `input type="search"` will do the trick.

##### Example

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="test">
```

Works regardless of whether the Kendo-UI library is used. In my case, I was using it with Kendo-Angular.